# How to set primary monitor and relation between monitors on ubuntu using terminal?

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors, display

In my Ubuntu there were an applet responsible for monitors management. Unfortunately after some updates (I didn't notice when exactly) this applet disappeared from "System Settings" applet. I wonder if there is any command line tool which manages monitors' properties. For example I want to change primary monitor from current one to another and to change orientation between them (which is left or which is right).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I figured it out. The command line tool is xrandr. The first step is to print all screens in the system by executing command:

```
xrandr
```

Next, when we know what the names are, we can adjust settings, in my case it was something like that:

```
xrandr --output DVI-I-1 --primary --right-of VGA-1
```

It set DVI-I-1 as primary monitor and 'moved' it on the right side of VGA-1 monitor.

Comment: If you just want to make some display primary: `xrandr --output DISPLAYID --primary`

Answer (score 0):

This command switches between two monitors:

```
xrandr --output $(xrandr --listactivemonitors | awk '/1:{print $4}') --primary
```

Comment: I get awk: cmd. line:1: /1:{print }
awk: cmd. line:1:  ^ unterminated regexp when attempting this.

Comment: `/1:` is not needed. This should work, `xrandr --output $(xrandr --listactivemonitors | awk '{print $4}') --primary`