# How to change primary display in KDE?

Tags: display, kde, kde5

I can't seem to find the option to make my second monitor as primary display, how may I change that?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You've provided no release details, thus if using Xorg or Wayland (active screen setting can control where windows will open but to be specific you release & thus software stack is needed).

Comment: @guiverc There is no currently supported version of Kubuntu running wayland by default (Kubuntu 21.04 uses xorg)

Answer (score 4):

Settings --> Display and Monitor --> Display Configuration

[image]

Comment: And how to do it via CLI?

Comment: @IvailoBardarov xrandr is your tool of choice (if you use x11) https://askubuntu.com/questions/925303/how-to-set-primary-monitor-and-relation-between-monitors-on-ubuntu-using-termina